ASP.NET Download Excel file and open with this error message ""
I have Problem when download excel from my system that built with ASP.NET 4.8 that using EPPLUS library for export excel.
In my local system, I am running code and downloading an Excel file, and can open it as normal without error. But when I deploy it to another port like 192.168…… this project can download Excel, but when I open the Excel file, it always has this error message

We found a problem with some content in 'LLOO (4).xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

This is my code
if (!blockExcel)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUploadExcel.FileName);
    ExcelFileManager.SaveAndDownloadExcel(diffData, fileNameWithoutExtension, Response);
}
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "showCustomAlert('Data Validated', 'blue');", true);
}
                    
public class ExcelFileManager
{
    public static void SaveAndDownloadExcel(DataTable diffData, string fileNameWithoutExtension, HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.ClearContent();

        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileNameWithoutExtension + ".xlsx");

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        }

        using (ExcelPackage diffPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet diffWorksheet = diffPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileNameWithoutExtension);
            for (int i = 0; i < diffData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                diffWorksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = diffData.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < diffData.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < diffData.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    diffWorksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 1].Value = diffData.Rows[row][col];
                }
            }

            diffPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filePath));
        }

        byte[] excelBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileNameWithoutExtension + ".xlsx");
        response.BinaryWrite(excelBytes);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
}

I am trying to find any solution for fixing this error message when opening the Excel file when I deploy to another server/

Some pointers that can make this happen: 1) Your sheet name is longer than 31 characters or 2) You have invalid characters in sheet name or 3) You have cells with values longer than 32k
